# Deveríamos poder usar itálico nos títulos?

Tags: novo-recurso, formatação, markdown, título

No SOpt comumente usamos palavras em inglês nos titulos, pela própria natureza das linguagens de programação.

Talvez não fizesse muito sentido nos sites primordiais da rede mas, para nós (assim como qualquer site de programação que não seja em inglês) faz todo sentido permitir o uso do itálico ou oblíquo também no título das questões.

Notando que a função do itálico neste contexto não seria de destacar pedaços da mensagem, mas apenas poder fazer o uso correto de termos em outras linguas (por isso fui específico quanto a itálico especificamente, e não a negrito).

Até pelo fato do mau uso de formatação normalmente ser ajustado pela comunidade, num primeiro momento não consigo imaginar motivos contra o uso do itálico ser estendido aos títulos (exceto a dor-de-cabeça técnica para implementar, mas aí já é com a SE :P ).

Comparação:

[Como melhorar esta função de “flattening” duma lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39837/)

[Como melhorar esta função de *flattening* duma lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39837/)

[Erro de “headers already sent” ao criar tabelas na ativação de plugin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39786/)

[Erro de *headers already sent* ao criar tabelas na ativação de *plugin*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39786/)

Comment: De minha parte, prefiro os títulos mais "limpos" mesmo... Só minha opinião, nada de objetivo contra.

Comment: Relacionado: [Fix Markdown/SmartyPants in question titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68844/185667) & [Can I use inline code formatting in question titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125335/185667)

Comment: @brasofilo a do -- dessa que você mencionou é pior ainda do que a falta de itálico :) . Mas coisa que muda a estética geral eu realmente acho um perigo, pq senão vira festa (o que não acho que seja o caso do itálico). Pra mim incomoda mais a grafia mesmo.

Comment: Nessa do SmartyPants tem um resposta do Atwood, acho que valeria a pena analisar os contras que ele oferece. . . . Não comprendo a que se refere com "grafia", itálico é considerado grafia? Seria legal ter uma referencia canônica sobre o assunto: é necessário itálico? aspas servem? qual a posição da ABL?

Comment: @brasofilo tecnicamente eu sei que pode ter alguma complicação, aspas resolveriam, mas eu andei testando e fica mais poluido. Pensei no itálico pq é muito discreto, e praticamente não afeta o visual geral da lista de perguntas, que é a porta de entrada pro site. Agora, é uma pergunta meio descontraída mesmo, pois está longe de ter uma importância significativa pro site. Temos coisas mais urgentes como a busca insensitiva em relação a acentuação, que aí sim é um problema de usabilidade básico.

Comment: Yes, +1 pela descontração dominical e +1000 para a busca insensitiva :) Fiz um [antes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4J9Q8.jpg) e [depois](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LwyKD.jpg), se quiser incorporar na pergunta

Comment: Eu acho que só o itálico é a solução. Todo o *markdown* seria problemático. As aspas sujam o título. Como eu acho que será rejeitado talvez a solução de pobre seria padronizar o uso de aspas nestes casos. Eu evito porque acho esquisito.

Comment: @brasofilo agradeço o antes e depois, eu tinha feito coisa do tipo, mas não tinha reunido bons exemplos. Vou ver se faço algo ou uso a sua versão depois, tinha pensado em algo um pouco mais "compacto" :)

Comment: yes, fiz só um teste rápido, algo mais ilustrativo seria ideal. Concordo com o @big aqui acima sobre sujeira, rejeição e probreza :p

Comment: Cara eu realmente não acho que seja legal... O design não fica bacana.